# Nginx proxy redirect on 8443/

Tags: nginx

We are currently using SSL on our Tomcat Server. but due to having to place the url in full it does come a pain. https://tomcat:8443/SubDomain it does confused some of our less technical end users that are reporting page is not loading.

in light of this I was hoping to use Nginx to redirect on port 80 to 8443 on our Tomcat Server since SSL is on Tomcat there is no need for Nginx to handle SSL. 
currently it just displaying the Nginx default Server page

```
upstream tomcat {
    server 127.0.0.1:8443;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location /subdomain/ {
            proxy_pass http://tomcat;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
          #  root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> since SSL is on Tomcat there is no need for Nginx to handle SSL

No, there still is. SSL/TLS doesn't "transfer" through a reverse proxy; it is hop-by-hop. So even though the `Nginx<->Tomcat` connection is secured with TLS, the `user<->Nginx` connection **is not** – unless you enable SSL/TLS in Nginx itself.

(Although your configuration doesn't tell Nginx to use TLS for the Tomcat connection either. Specifying the port is not enough; you still need to use `proxy_pass https://<backend>`.)

> currently it just displaying the Nginx default Server page

That's expected, because your configuration doesn't proxy all paths; it only proxies URLs starting with `http://<nginx>/subdomain/`.